# UIGraphics Memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigraphicscontext

There seems to be a memory leak in this code, but I cannot find it. What am I doing wrong? Specifically, lines 1 and 2 add to the apps memory usage, and only the memory from line one goes away when the context is ended.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

EDIT 1:
Full method code below:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width + 16 - ((int)self.view.frame.size.width % 16), self.view.frame.size.height + 16 - ((int)self.view.frame.size.height % 16))]; // If image width and height is not a multiple of 16, the video becomes distorted when written to a file
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

[imageView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ViewController makeRedCircle]]];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: What makes you think there's a leak?

Comment: @matt It adds a couple of megabytes to memory permanently every time its run. I tested the app on an iPhone 6 using Xcode.

Comment: Did you use Instruments? - Also what is `image`? What are you doing with it later? In other words, can you give me code that I can actually run in order to reproduce your leak?

Comment: We can pretty conclusively say there's no memory leak in this sample of code.  What happens with newImage after this code runs we can't say.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Voting to close on that basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherent about your code that leaks:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Nor is there any evidence of a leak. To test, I created an app whose only code is as follows:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView* imageView = self.imageView;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        // Here is your code in action!
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size);
        [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}

@end
```

There is no leak; successive iterations of the loop do not add to the app's memory.

Therefore we can conclude that if your app's memory is growing, it's because of something else you're doing (such as what you're doing with the image later on).